# How to get Angular getter and setter working?

Tags: angular, setter

trying to apply 'Intercept input property changes with a setter' from the angular.io guide. the template of the child shows, but no changes are being made to the input of the parent..?? it worked before :-) :-(

This is the child component: ts and html:

ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { BowlingGame } from '../model/bowling-game.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-generate-result',
  templateUrl: './generate-result.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./generate-result.component.css']
})

export class GenerateResultComponent {
  @Input()
  get game(): BowlingGame { return this._game; }
  set game(game: BowlingGame) {
  this._game.rolls[0] = game.rolls[0] + 15;
  this._game = game;
  }
  private _game = { rolls: <number[]>[], player: "", isActive: true };
}
```

the html: `<h2>generate-result.component.html {{game | json}}</h2>`

And the parent component, the html file:
I include everything, because I don't know if it is a bad practice that this parent has many children.. ? The app-generate-result child is on the first line of the code..

```
<app-generate-result *ngIf="bowlingGamePlayer1" [game]="bowlingGamePlayer1"></app-generate-result>

<h1>Insert your Roll score (dashboard for 2 players)</h1>
<div class="player1" *ngIf="bowlingGamePlayer1.isActive" >
  <h2>Input Player 1:</h2>
<app-create-roll-item (onRollCreated)="insertRollPlayer1($event)"></app-create-roll-item>
</div>

<div *ngIf="bowlingGamePlayer2.isActive" class="player2">
  <h2>Input Player 2: </h2>
<app-create-roll-item (onRollCreated)="insertRollPlayer2($event)"></app-create-roll-item>
</div>

<h2>bowlingGame1 | json (from parent:app.comp): {{bowlingGamePlayer1 | json}}</h2>

<!-- results are displayed in parent: app.component.html -->
<table>

  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="3">frame1</td>
    <td colspan="3">frame2</td>
    <td colspan ="3">frame3</td>
    <td colspan ="3">frame4</td>
    <td colspan ="3">frame5</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="player1">
    <td>Player:1</td>
    <td *ngFor="let score of bowlingGamePlayer1.rolls">{{score}}</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="player2">
    <td>Player:2</td>
    <td *ngFor="let score of bowlingGamePlayer2.rolls">{{score}}</td>
  </tr>


</table>


<h1>rollsPlayer1</h1>
<h2>{{rollsPlayer1 | json}}</h2>
<!--
<h1>rollsPerFramePlayer1</h1>
<h2>{{rollsPerFramePlayer1 | json}}</h2>
-->
<h3>indexRollFrame</h3>
<h3>{{indexRollFrame}}</h3><h3>rollsPerFrame: {{rollsPerFrame | json }}</h3>

<h1>totalPins</h1>
<h2>{{totalPins}}</h2>
<h1>rolls player 2 length: {{rollsPlayer2.length}} /// max nr rolls {{maxNumberRollsPlayer2}}</h1>
<h1>rolls player 1 length: {{rollsPlayer1.length}} /// max nr rolls {{maxNumberRollsPlayer1}}</h1>
<h1>index frame player 1/ player2</h1>
<h2>{{indexFramePlayer1 }}/ {{indexFramePlayer2}}</h2> -->
```

the ts of the parent (for completeness reasons):

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { BowlingGame } from './model/bowling-game.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  bowlingGamePlayer1
  bowlingGamePlayer2
  rollsPlayer1
  rollsPlayer2
  rollsPerFrame
  // total pinns trown !!
  totalPins = 0;
  //  roll index in frame (range: 0 -1- 2)
  indexRollFrame = 0;
  // index frame: 0-4 (5 frames) , frame 5 is special: strike/spare in 5th frame
  indexFramePlayer1 = 0;
  indexFramePlayer2 = 0;
  rollZero = 0;

  maxNumberRollsPlayer1 = 15;
  maxNumberRollsPlayer2 = 15;
  // leave constructor empty of the real work
  constructor() {
    this.bowlingGamePlayer1 = new BowlingGame([], "player1", true);
    this.bowlingGamePlayer2 = new BowlingGame([], "player2", false);
    this.rollsPlayer1 = this.bowlingGamePlayer1.rolls;
    this.rollsPlayer2 = this.bowlingGamePlayer2.rolls;
    this.totalPins = 0;
    this.rollsPerFrame = <number[]>[];
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  passToNextPlayer() {
    this.bowlingGamePlayer1.isActive = !this.bowlingGamePlayer1.isActive;
    this.bowlingGamePlayer2.isActive = !this.bowlingGamePlayer2.isActive;
    this.indexRollFrame = 0;
    this.totalPins = 0;
    this.rollsPerFrame = [];
  }

// try to make a function per frame: check! // spare = 15 pins after 2 OR 3 rolls!
  insertRollPlayer1(r:number):void {
    // after execution: length == maxNumberRolls :-)
    if (this.rollsPlayer1.length < (this.maxNumberRollsPlayer1)) {
      this.rollsPlayer1.push(r)
        // put the scores per frame in a rollsPerFrame variable
        this.rollsPerFrame[this.indexRollFrame] = r; // array [0,0,0], starts with indexRollFrame 0

        this.totalPins += this.rollsPerFrame[this.indexRollFrame]; // number, starts with 0
        //  // starting from frame 5 (index is 4 beforehand) apply other logic !!! frame 5 is longer than the other frames!
        if ((this.indexFramePlayer1 == 4) && (this.totalPins < 15) && (this.indexRollFrame == 2)) {
          this.passToNextPlayer();
        } else if ((this.indexFramePlayer1 == 4) && (this.totalPins < 15) && (this.indexRollFrame < 2)) {
          this.indexRollFrame += 1;
        }
        // set max number of rolls, based on 5th frame. Frame 5 is not limited to three rolls!
        if(this.indexFramePlayer1 == 4 && this.totalPins == 15) {
          if(this.indexRollFrame==0) {
            this.maxNumberRollsPlayer1 = 16;
            this.indexRollFrame += 1;
        // case spare in 2 rolls
          } else if (this.indexRollFrame == 1) {
            this.maxNumberRollsPlayer1 = 16;
            this.indexRollFrame += 1;
            // spare in 3 rolls // edge case! this could be the last roll!
          } else if (this.indexRollFrame == 2) {
            this.maxNumberRollsPlayer1 = 17;
            this.indexRollFrame += 1;
            }
          }
        // set the logic for the end of the game, in case of spare or strike in last frame
        if(this.indexFramePlayer1 == 4 && this.totalPins > 15) {
          if(this.rollsPlayer1.length == this.maxNumberRollsPlayer1) {
            this.passToNextPlayer();
          }
        }
        if (this.indexFramePlayer1 < 4) {
          if (this.totalPins == 15) {
            // if strike
            if (this.indexRollFrame == 0) {
              // this.rollsPlayer1.push(this.rollZero);
              // this.rollsPlayer1.push(this.rollZero);
              this.indexFramePlayer1 += 1;
              this.passToNextPlayer();
              // case spare after 2 rolls
            } else if (this.indexRollFrame == 1) {
              // this.rollsPlayer1.push(this.rollZero);
              this.indexFramePlayer1 += 1;
              this.passToNextPlayer();
              // case 15 pins after 3 rolls
            } else {
              this.indexFramePlayer1 += 1;
              this.passToNextPlayer()
            }
            // case not 15 pins in total after 3 rolls
          } else if (this.indexRollFrame == 2) {
            this.indexFramePlayer1 += 1;
            this.passToNextPlayer()
            // case if frame is not over yet
          } else {
            this.indexRollFrame += 1;
          }
        }
    }
  }

// two functions for player 1/ player2 because you don't get the info from the form which player is at turn
  insertRollPlayer2(r:number):void {
    if (this.rollsPlayer2.length < (this.maxNumberRollsPlayer2)) {
      this.rollsPlayer2.push(r)
      this.rollsPerFrame[this.indexRollFrame] = r; // array [0,0,0], starts with indexRollFrame 0
      this.totalPins += this.rollsPerFrame[this.indexRollFrame]; // number, starts with 0
      // start with cases in frame 5
      if (this.indexFramePlayer2 == 4 && this.totalPins < 15 && this.indexRollFrame == 2) {
        this.bowlingGamePlayer2.isActive = false;
      }
      if (this.indexFramePlayer2 == 4 && this.totalPins < 15 && this.indexRollFrame < 2) {
        this.indexRollFrame += 1;
      }
      // set max number of rolls, based on 5th frame. Frame 5 is not limited to three rolls!
      if (this.indexFramePlayer2 == 4 && this.totalPins == 15) {
        if (this.indexRollFrame == 0) {
          this.maxNumberRollsPlayer2 = 16;
          this.indexRollFrame += 1;
          // case spare in 2 rolls
        } else if (this.indexRollFrame == 1) {
          this.maxNumberRollsPlayer2 = 16;
          this.indexRollFrame += 1;
          // spare in 3 rolls // edge case! this could be the last roll!
        } else if (this.indexRollFrame == 2) {
          this.maxNumberRollsPlayer2 = 17;
          this.indexRollFrame += 1;
        }
      }
      // set the logic for the end of the game, in case of spare or strike in last frame
      if (this.indexFramePlayer2 == 4 && this.totalPins > 15) {
        if (this.rollsPlayer2.length == this.maxNumberRollsPlayer2) {
          this.bowlingGamePlayer2.isActive = false;
        }
      }
      if (this.indexFramePlayer2 < 4) {
        if (this.totalPins == 15) {
          // if strike
          if (this.indexRollFrame == 0) {
            // this.rollsPlayer2.push(this.rollZero);
            // this.rollsPlayer2.push(this.rollZero);
            this.indexFramePlayer2 += 1;
            this.passToNextPlayer();
            // case spare
          } else if (this.indexRollFrame == 1) {
            // this.rollsPlayer2.push(this.rollZero);
            this.indexFramePlayer2 += 1;
            this.passToNextPlayer();
            // case 15 pins after 3 rolls
          } else {
            this.indexFramePlayer2 += 1;
            this.passToNextPlayer()
          }
          // case not 15 pins in total
        } else if (this.indexRollFrame == 2) {
          this.indexFramePlayer2 += 1;
          this.passToNextPlayer()
        } else {
          this.indexRollFrame += 1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basic get/set setup is as such:

Backing property to store the value, a setter method (typically as part of an `@Input()` as you have), and a getter method.

```
private _someValue: string;

@Input() public set someValue(value: string) {
    this._someValue = value;
    // this.nowDoSomethingElse();
}

public get someValue(): string { return this._value; }
```

Every time the input value to this component changes, it'll hit inside that set method so you can do whatever else you need to do.

The getter is optional, really, but having a getter means that the template has ready access to the value for use (templates can only access public members, not private).

One thing to be wary of is change detection. If it's a string or other value/primitive type, then changes to it are recognised as a new value and into the set method you go.

If you have an object/reference type, then changes to *properties* in that object won't cause you to enter happy fun setter land. For that, you need to either set up your own changed detection or actually give it a new object reference.

Quick and easy object reference change:

```
this.myThing = {...this.myThing};
```

Once your object reference has changed like this, into the world of setter methods you go.

---

Slightly more targeted answer now I have the leisure.

You can do it in a wasteful way, constantly recreating the game object, or you can just pass the minimum amount of data into your result component.

Does it really need to know about the entirety of the game, or just some key values? I suspect the latter. In which case, you just want the minimal going in, and you can more tightly control that in your parent.

Score component:

```
@Input() public data: ScoringDataDto;
```

Parent component:

```
private _scoreDetails: ScoringDataDto;
public get scoreDetails(): ScoringDataDto { return this._scoreDetails; }

private updateGame(...): void {
    // update the game or something
    // ...

    this.updateScoring(...);
}

private updateScoring(...): void {
    this._scoreDetails = {rolls: this._game.rolls, active: true, whatever: 'else'};
}
```

Create a new scoring object whenever you update it, and changes will automatically be registered in the scoring component.

Don't be afraid to just copy out the bits of data that you need. It's not nearly as messy as it might seem and quickly becomes second nature. It also becomes easier to read and manage, and helps you to architect your solution better by reducing the size of everything down to a 'need to know basis'.

Angular is a component-based system, after all, not a monolith.
Parent template:

```
<app-score-display [data]="scoreDetails"></app-score-display>
```

Comment: ah that's a good one, to change the object reference, through spread operator! nice fix.

Comment: ah that's a good one, to change the object reference, through spread operator! nice fix. I just cannot figure out how to make it work, but many thanks @Krenom ! If I don't find a solution, I will contintue with ngOnChanges() ..